# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'value-domain') in React.Js

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am having a problem that I don't know where it cause. Please help me out.

I am developing a stock management platform, it allows users to CRUD products.

When Users are on the product page, they will see a table with edit and delete buttons in every record.

Whenever they click on the delete button, it will show a PopOver to confirm the delete action.

And the error happens when I click "Yes" in the PopOver Component

I am using Material-UI version 4.12.3,

Here is my parent component:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
    modal: {
        display: "flex",
        alignItems: "center",
        justifyContent: "center",
    },
    paper: {
        backgroundColor: theme.palette.background.paper,
        border: "2px solid #000",
        boxShadow: theme.shadows[5],
        padding: theme.spacing(2, 4, 3),
    },
    loading: {
        display: "flex",
        justifyContent: "center",
    },
}));

const useRowStyles = makeStyles({
    root: {
        "& > *": {
            borderBottom: "100%",
        },
    },
});

function createData(id, name, supplier, type, unit, quantity, cost, price, ingredients, action) {
    return {
        id,
        name,
        supplier,
        type,
        unit,
        quantity,
        cost,
        price,
        ingredients,
        action,
    };
}

function Row(props) {
    const { row } = props;
    const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);
    const classes = useRowStyles();

    const isCocktail = (type) => {
        if (type === "Cocktail" || type === "Mocktail") {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    };
    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <TableRow className={classes.root}>
                <TableCell>
                    {isCocktail(row.type) ? (
                        <IconButton aria-label="expand row" size="small" onClick={() => setOpen(!open)}>
                            {open ? <KeyboardArrowUpIcon /> : <KeyboardArrowDownIcon />}
                        </IconButton>
                    ) : null}
                </TableCell>
                <TableCell component="th" scope="row">
                    {row.id}
                </TableCell>
                <TableCell align="middle">{row.name}</TableCell>
                <TableCell align="middle">{row.supplier}</TableCell>
                <TableCell align="middle">{row.type}</TableCell>
                <TableCell align="middle">{row.unit}</TableCell>
                <TableCell align="middle">{row.quantity}</TableCell>
                <TableCell align="middle">{row.cost}</TableCell>
                <TableCell align="middle">{row.price}</TableCell>
                <TableCell align="middle">{row.action}</TableCell>
            </TableRow>
            <TableRow></TableRow>
        </React.Fragment>
    );
}

function Ingredients({ controller }) {
    const classes = useStyles();
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const loading = useSelector((state) => state.product.loading);
    const listProducts = useSelector((state) => state?.product?.products?.products);
    const role = useSelector((state) => state.auth.user.role);
    const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);

    const nonCocktailList = listProducts?.filter((e) => e.type !== "Cocktail");
    const nonMocktailList = nonCocktailList?.filter((e) => e.type !== "Mocktail");
    const nonFoodList = nonMocktailList?.filter((e) => e.type !== "Food");

    const handleOpen = async (id) => {
        await dispatch(productActions.getSingleProduct(id));
        setOpen(true);
    };
    const handleClose = () => {
        setOpen(false);
    };

    let vietNamD = Intl.NumberFormat("vi-VI");
    let rows = nonFoodList?.map((product, index) => {
        return createData(
            index,
            product?.name,
            product?.supplier,
            product?.unit,
            `${product?.capacity + " " + product?.capacityUnit}`,
            `${vietNamD.format(product?.cost)} đ`,
            `${product?.quantity + " " + product?.unit}`,
            <div className="actions">
                <Button variant="contained" style={{ backgroundColor: "#2EC0FF", color: "white" }} onClick={() => handleOpen(product?._id)}>
                    <EditOutlinedIcon style={{ color: "white" }} />
                </Button>
                <PopOver id={product._id} role={role} controller={controller} />
            </div>
        );
    });

    useEffect(() => {
        dispatch(supplierActions.getSuppliers());
    }, [dispatch]);

    return loading ? (
        <div className={classes.loading}>
            {" "}
            <CircularProgress />
        </div>
    ) : (
        <div className="create-button">
            <Modal
                aria-labelledby="transition-modal-title"
                aria-describedby="transition-modal-description"
                className={classes.modal}
                open={open}
                onClose={handleClose}
                closeAfterTransition
                BackdropComponent={Backdrop}
                BackdropProps={{
                    timeout: 500,
                }}
            >
                <Fade in={open}>
                    <CreateUpdateIngredient handleClose={handleClose} controller={controller} />
                </Fade>
            </Modal>

            <IngredientModal controller={controller} />
            <TableContainer component={Paper}>
                <Table aria-label="collapsible table">
                    <TableHead style={{ backgroundColor: "black", width: "100%" }}>
                        <TableRow>
                            <TableCell />
                            <TableCell style={{ color: "white" }}>Index</TableCell>
                            <TableCell style={{ color: "white" }} align="middle">
                                Name
                            </TableCell>
                            <TableCell style={{ color: "white" }} align="middle">
                                Supplier
                            </TableCell>
                            <TableCell style={{ color: "white" }} align="middle">
                                Unit
                            </TableCell>
                            <TableCell style={{ color: "white" }} align="middle">
                                Unit Capacity
                            </TableCell>
                            <TableCell style={{ color: "white" }} align="middle">
                                Cost
                            </TableCell>
                            <TableCell style={{ color: "white" }} align="middle">
                                Daily Quantity Needed
                            </TableCell>
                            <TableCell
                                style={{
                                    color: "white",
                                    display: "flex",
                                    justifyContent: "center",
                                }}
                                align="middle"
                            >
                                Action
                            </TableCell>
                        </TableRow>
                    </TableHead>
                    <TableBody>
                        {rows?.map((row) => (
                            <Row key={row.id} row={row} />
                        ))}
                    </TableBody>
                </Table>
            </TableContainer>
        </div>
    );
}
export default React.memo(Ingredients);
```

And this is the PopOver:

```
    import React from "react";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import Popover from "@material-ui/core/Popover";
import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";
import { Button, IconButton } from "@material-ui/core";
import DeleteOutlineOutlinedIcon from "@material-ui/icons/DeleteOutlineOutlined";
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { productActions } from "redux/actions";

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
    typography: {
        padding: theme.spacing(2),
    },
}));

export default function PopOver(props) {
    const { controller, id, role } = props;
    const classes = useStyles();
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = React.useState(null);

    const deleteProduct = (id) => {
        if (!id) return;
        dispatch(productActions.deleteProduct(id));
        dispatch(productActions.getProducts(controller));
        handleClose();
    };

    const handleClick = (event) => {
        setAnchorEl(event.currentTarget);
    };

    const handleClose = () => {
        setAnchorEl(null);
    };

    const open = Boolean(anchorEl);
    const productId = open ? "simple-popover" : undefined;
    return (
        <div>
            <Button aria-describedby={id} style={{ backgroundColor: "#FF4D4F", height: "40px", width: "20px" }} variant="contained" onClick={handleClick} disabled={role !== "Admin"}>
                <IconButton aria-label="delete" color="secondary">
                    <DeleteOutlineOutlinedIcon style={{ color: "white" }} />
                </IconButton>
            </Button>
            <Popover
                id={productId}
                open={open}
                anchorEl={anchorEl}
                onClose={handleClose}
                anchorOrigin={{
                    vertical: "bottom",
                    horizontal: "center",
                }}
                transformOrigin={{
                    vertical: "top",
                    horizontal: "center",
                }}
            >
                <Typography className={classes.typography}>
                    Do you want to delete this ingredient?
                    <Button
                        color="primary"
                        onClick={() => {
                            deleteProduct(id);
                        }}
                    >
                        Yes
                    </Button>
                    <Button color="secondary" onClick={handleClose}>
                        No
                    </Button>
                </Typography>
            </Popover>
        </div>
    );
}
```

These are the two actions that called when a record is deleted

```
const getProducts =
    ({ date, mode }) =>
    async (dispatch) => {
        const body = { date, mode };
        dispatch({ type: types.GET_PRODUCTS_REQUEST, payload: null });
        try {
            const res = await api.post("/products", body);
            dispatch({ type: types.GET_PRODUCTS_SUCCESS, payload: res.data.data });
        } catch (error) {
            toast.error("Get Product List Failed");
            dispatch({ type: types.GET_PRODUCTS_FAILURE, payload: error });
        }
    };

const deleteProduct = (id) => async (dispatch) => {
    dispatch({ type: types.DELETE_PRODUCT_REQUEST, payload: null });
    try {
        const res = await api.delete(`/products/${id}`);
        dispatch({ type: types.DELETE_PRODUCT_SUCCESS, payload: res.data.data });
        toast.success("Delete Product Success");
    } catch (error) {
        toast.error("Delete Product Fail");
        dispatch({ type: types.DELETE_PRODUCT_FAILURE, payload: error });
    }
};
```

Comment: I think you should explain more briefly what is the exact issue you encounter.

Comment: Thank you for further explaining. It seems the issue is not in the part of the code that you brought here, but maybe in `productActions` class in `redux/actions`. Can you bring the relevant code ?

Comment: Thank you Alon, I have updated the redux actions. You can check it

Comment: Chekc button onclik => handclick what return, then check if id exist then delete. Use some console logs check what's happening

Comment: Thanks Nijat, the handleClick is to target the button to show the PopOver, I have added the if id exist condition to check then delete and it still got the same error

Comment: Probably it is popupover. Comment this component try simple js confirm metod. I think when you clicked popup yes it is trigger to close popup and handleclose called set value null then some error happens